# interactively watch other users action on server

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, ubuntu-10.10

im having some server issues and called for support. 
i would like to be able to view the support persons action on the terminal in real time from a different location. possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU Screen is the easiest way.  `screen -x` allows you to attach to an existing screen session from another terminal.  `screen -xR` will do the same, but also start a new session if no suitable existing screen session exists.  More info in the [GNU Screen Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Answer (score 2):

[ttysnoop](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ttysnoop/) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).